# How to have objects/Controls GC'd despite being subscribed to an event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have objects subscribing to a custom event so I can change them all them at once. Trouble is, that that will never let them go out of scope and be garbage-collected. Even nulling Controls will not null the Controls contained in them. In fact, even the nulled controls will not be collected! (Please do correct me if I'm wrong on any point.)

So I thought of a solution which would be to wrap the event in a class, create an instance of that class and use it, and then null it when I want to let the objects get GC'd, and create a new instance of it to continue.

However, I have two questions about it:

1. Will it actually work, or will the objects still evade being GC'd?
2. Is there any simpler, more straightforward way to achieve this?

EDIT: part 2 has been answered (in a comment to an answer). Simply do: `event_name = null;`. I'm still wondering, though, about part 1 - would it work?

Comment: The [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) is very useful for this sort of problem.

Comment: @vcsjones Looks nice. But it seems to be for WPF. I'm using winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to part 2 (by Servy's comments):

```
event_name = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to unsubscribe from your event. This works just like subscribing, but uses the `-=` operator instead of `+=`.

Example:

```
foo.SomeEvent-= new EventHandler(foo_SomeEvent);
```

Comment: I don't want to have to go recursively through all of them for that.  One of the intentions of that event is to _not_ have to keep track of all objects that subscribe to it. But thanks.

Comment: @ispiro You don't have the owner of the event do the unsubscribing, you have whatever subscribed to the event do the unsubscribing.

Comment: @Servy Good point. Is there a way I can unsubscribe _all_ subscriptions of an event? Will `event_name = null;` do it without eliminating that event altogether?

Comment: The only caveat with that approach is that it will force *all* consumers to unsubscribe. That may or may not be acceptable in this application -- just be aware of what you are doing.

Comment: @Servy Doesn't seem to work. I Just tried `event_name = null;
event_name(null, null);` - throws an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @ispiro That's because you're not supposed to trigger events that are null.  You would get the same error if you just tried to trigger an event that never was subscribed to in the first place.  As long as the code that triggers the event checks for null (any event firing code should always do so) it won't be a problem.

Comment: @Servy oops. My mistake. Perhaps change your original comment into an answer.